# Schedule to run a program and click some radiobutton and button in sequence

Tags: windows, automation, schedule

Is it possible to automate a program in windows and run a sequential click of each control and buttton. for example click some radiobutton to configure some setting and press enter.

For an example, Is it possible if i run this cauculator program once a day click 1+1 then click equal and close this program after it finished execution or at a certain amount of time for example 1 15 minute

[image]

Add More information : i have a program that my boss want to run this once a day. I have to click the same radio button setting everyday and press enter. i have no source code of it i am just an end user. i am looking for a way to automate this

Comment: Are you meaning programmatically, or are you looking for an end-user utility to do this? If so - which language? :)

Comment: @Ninefingers more information added

Comment: thanks. We have a site for PC enthusiasts that can probably help out far better called Super User - hang tight and we'll move your question there in short order :) (please don't cross post!)

Comment: Oh.. you are right. i should had posted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you really intend, but [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) might be your weapon of choice for the automation part. The scheduling can also be done in AutoHotKey or with the Windows inbuilt task scheduler.